# LWC Static Resource Fonts

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources

I am trying to load fonts from a static resource into my LWC component. I have tried using loadStyle and loadScript from platformResourceLoader but neither work. Are there any other methods that may import fonts from static resources or locally?

These are the errors I receive:

With loadStyle:

> Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

With loadScript:

> (index):1 Uncaught (in promise) undefined

Regards

Comment: When you uploaded the stylesheet what's the MIME type of it in the static resource ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css class I created had the path to the folder like this: /fonts/font.woff.

The solution was to use the relative path with ./fonts/font.woff. After changing that the fonts loaded using loadStyle. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Example of loading static resource fonts in LWC**

**Static Resource Structure**
[image: Static Resource Structure]

**style.css**

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gilroy';
    src: url('fonts/Gilroy-Medium.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Gilroy-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/Gilroy-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/Gilroy-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.customClass {
    font-family: 'Girloy', Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

**LWC JS file**

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import sResource from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/customStyle';

export default class TestCmp extends LightningElement {

  renderedCallback() {
      loadStyle(this, sResource + '/style.css')
        .then(() => {});
  }
}
```